# How to add weights to circuit board standoffs(spacers) of a acrylic board?

Tags: plastic, acrylic-glass

I am using acrylic boards to make a desktop file organizer. The area of the bottom is 8"x4", and it has 4 legs. I will use circuit board standoffs(spacers) as the legs. The height of each leg will be between 30mm ~ 50mm. I need to add weight to the bottom of each leg separately to make the bottom heavier. I was thinking about using coins, but would like to know other alternatives that are better and look nicer,

My question:
How to add weight to the bottom of each leg so the bottom is heavier? (I don't want to add a second layer of an acrylic board to the bottom of the legs. )

Thanks in advance for sharing your ideas. :)

Comment: What is the purpose of the weight? To prevent tipping when the organizer has imbalanced loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purposes, one can expect that more weight, as low as possible, will accomplish your objective. With circuit board standoffs, you have a threaded hole at one end and a threaded stud at the other. This provides for easily attached weights in various forms.

You've considered coins, which if chosen successfully, can be attractive. Think various sizes of coins from countries around the world, with holes drilled to accept the bolt you'll use to attach to the standoff.

US coins are somewhat lightweight and poorly suited for such a project, in my opinion. Masses composed of lead will provide the best weight per volume but lead has its own complications. It's not dangerous to handle but there are some health considerations. I have a cupcake tin that I use to make lead ingots, about 80 mm in diameter and 30 mm thick, probably too large for your purpose. I then dipped them in a product called [PlastiDip](https://plastidip.com/our-products/plasti-dip/) which is also available in spray form.

If this is attractive to you, it's a matter of picking a suitable mold (silicone molds can work) and finding someone to pour. Fishermen will frequently create their own sinkers and avid weapons owners will cast their own rounds, providing at least two resources for you.

If lead doesn't cut it, steel would be the next available option. Steel washers, both stainless and galvanized forms are available at big box stores and mom-and-pop hardware stores as well. Pick a size for your taste and aim for either the hole size to match the thread size of the hole, or match the hole size to the outside diameter of your stand-off.

Even with the possibly-unsightly washer option, you can still apply PlastiDip spray to provide a colorful rubber coating for surface protection and cosmetic appeal.

Comment: Brass is slightly denser than steel, but more expensive.  It's a good material to consider as it's easy to cut threads into, and gives you more options for finding stock parts to use/modify.

Comment: fred makes a good point that the stand-offs are threaded. Look into threaded steel balls attached to the ends of your legs. A google of 'threaded steel balls' presents many options.